# RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider Encrypt command not working

Tags: c#, encryption, app-config

I Am following [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/encrypting-app-config-for-multiple-machines/) step by step.

While performing steps in the step of executing this command

> aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings . -prov MyEncryptionProvider

I am getting the error

> The protection provider 'MyEncryptionProvider ' was not found

Please advice what might be the issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>    
  <configProtectedData>
    <providers>
      <add keyContainerName="MyCustomKeys"
       useMachineContainer="true"
       description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt"
       name="MyEncryptionProvider"
    type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider,System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="xxxxx" />
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="xxxxx=" />
    <add key="Realm" value="x-xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you post your web.config file?

Comment: @spodger : added config xml

Comment: you realise it needs to be named web.config?

Comment: yeah then only it works

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your file to web.config before running

`aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings . -prov MyEncryptionProvider`

then rename it it back to config.xml afterwards.

Comment: I thought your comment "yeah then only it works" suggested it did so I posted it as the answer.